SharePoint 2010 workflow task stuck "In Progress"
I am using SharePoint 2010 designer workflow in 2016 on premise. Workflow's overall status is shown as In Progress and the task assigned has status Not Started. Once user completes the task then task status is changed to Completed.
If I update task item directly using PowerShell for e.g. changing user to whom task is assigned, then the task status is changed to In Progress and it remains like this and doesn't move forward. Then I have to end the workflow.
How can I update task list item directly using PowerShell and still keep status as Not Started?
The same behaviour also happens if the user who is completing task is not the one to whom task is assigned. In that case too, task status will change to In Progress instead of Completed
